# Print while testing

Tags: android, android-studio

I add several lines of System.out.println("xxx") in my junit test class but I can only see whether I pass the test not my printed message. I'm using android studio and how can I see the printed message in a junit test? Thanks!

Comment: Log.e("message","XXX");   try Log class

Comment: can you please past your gradle here,

Answer (score 0):

You can use filters to limit the number of messages. Using multiple levels of logging, like verbose you can also limit the number of messages.

Perhaps it would be better to use `Log.d('Chongye', 'This is my message');` Since you can filter your username and see if it is logged correctly. More information can be found here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you have tried this?

```
Log.e("YOUR TITLE MESSAGE", "THE MESSAGE");
```

You can see the message on android monitor.